# DropDown a ComboBox in a sheet, NOT on a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

In an Excel sheet, NOT on a UserForm - Trying to come up with a code to be able to drop down a combo box, i.e. to get it to open. Might use it to trigger with hover over a shape. But, get a "Compile error: Invalid use of Me keyword", and without "Me." get "Run-time error '424': Object required"

```
Sub ActivateCB1()
ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Activate
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Me` only works in a code module attached to (eg) a worksheet or userform

```vb
Sub ActivateCB1()
    With ActiveSheet.ComboBox1
        .Activate
        .DropDown
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams.  What's the opposite of .DropDown, for when I want to make it close as mouse rolls off the text box?

Comment: No idea but some related hits here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+combobox+dropdown+opposite